# Is it possible to query distinct on arbitrary number of columns individually in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a table with several columns each containing duplicates. We need to query it in such a way that the result contains only distinct elements in each column of an arbitrary subset of all columns individually and not only individual tuples.

Let me illustrate the problem with an example, given the following table

```
 color | type  | vendor | price 
-------+-------+--------+-------
 red   | apple | smith  |     1
 red   | apple | cooper |     2
 red   | pear  | smith  |     3
 red   | pear  | cooper |     4
 green | apple | smith  |     1
 green | apple | cooper |     2
 green | pear  | smith  |     3
 green | pear  | cooper |     4
```

a typical query asking for distinct elements (where always the cheapest is chosen) would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (color, type)
  color,
  type,
  vendor,
  price
FROM fruits
ORDER BY
  color,
  type,
  price;
```

with the following result

```
 color | type  | vendor | price 
-------+-------+--------+-------
 green | apple | smith  |     1
 green | pear  | smith  |     3
 red   | apple | smith  |     1
 red   | pear  | smith  |     3
```

However the desired result should be distinct on both columns color and type individually, i.e.

```
 color | type  | vendor | price 
-------+-------+--------+-------
 green | apple | smith  |     1
 red   | pear  | smith  |     3
```

We are wondering if there is a solution working for an arbitrary number of columns, i.e. `DISTINCT ON INDIVIDUALLY (color, type) ...`. If this is not possible the next best solution would work with a given maximum number of columns, i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT ON MAX_INDIVIDUAL ($COLUMNS)` where `$COLUMNS` can be either 1, 2 or 3 columns but never more. The minimum requirement would be a solution for a fixed number of columns. However, the latter can be naively implemented using subqueries.

The problem of ordering by price as in the example above does not need to be treated in a mathematically exact way.

The above table can be setup with

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fruits;

CREATE TABLE fruits (
  color TEXT,
  type TEXT,
  vendor TEXT,
  price INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO fruits VALUES
  ('red', 'apple', 'smith', 1),
  ('red', 'apple', 'cooper', 2),
  ('red', 'pear', 'smith', 3),
  ('red', 'pear', 'cooper', 4),
  ('green', 'apple', 'smith', 1),
  ('green', 'apple', 'cooper', 2),
  ('green', 'pear', 'smith', 3),
  ('green', 'pear', 'cooper', 4);
```

Note: We are aware that there a several questions already asked which look very similar on first glance, however none of them is covering the issue described above in it's generality.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?

Comment: @joop No they do not. Would this make a difference?

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference. `{color,type,vendor}` *appears* to be a candidate key, though, and could be considered the PK.

Comment: what is the sorting criteria for your desired result ?? do you want to consider `price`

Comment: @dude Yes, sorry for not being explicit on this. I edit.

Comment: so highest price or what ??

Comment: you want to consider `color` ,`type` not `vendor` and what for `price` (the maxima) or what ??

Comment: Note: this problem gets harder if the {color,type,vendor} grid is incomplete. Currently, all possible 2*2*2=8 tuples exist. (this is the reason why Lennart's solution works)

Comment: @dude Correct, maximum or minimum, but not an arbitrary one.

Comment: @joop You are right. We are not even sure that is is solvable in SQL at all. Do you have an opinion on this?

Comment: You can try CTE to work it

Comment: Still working on it! As I said, the problem comes close to PJ/NF (3 sets of composite 2-member keys; (maybe) except for the vendor-column)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select color, type, max(vendor), min(price) 
from (
    select color, type, vendor, price
         , dense_rank() over (order by color) as rn1
         , dense_rank() over (order by type) as rn2 
    from fruits
) x
where rn1 = rn2 
group by color, type
```

should give a sample of color and type. The aggregates (randomly chosen) should pick one value for each sample.

Comment: Thank you @Lennart, this works. Do I understand correctly that the ordering in arbitrary? Do you see an option to order by price, i.e. choose the cheapest of the `red` rows instead of a random one?

Comment: Do you mean that you would like (read, pear, 1) or (red, apple, 1)?

Comment: In your query you select a vendor and a price which does not need to be in the same row. This is critical in our case, i.e. when need to choose the (full) row with the lowest price, not only the lowest price itself. In the example given this is unfortunately not very obvious, though.

Comment: Ok, as I understand it the result has to be "closed", i.e. the result of the query should be a sub-set of fruits. Are we guaranteed to have the same number of distinct color and type?

Comment: The same number of distinct color and type is not guaranteed.

Comment: There has to be something that I'm missing cause I don't understand how the task could be solved. If fruits contain (red, apple, cooper, 1), (red, pear, cooper, 1), what would the result of the query be?

Comment: I'm also not sure if it can be solved at all. For you example either of the rows (but only one) would be a valid result, because for (red, apple) and (red, pear) color and type are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution for this.  If you think about the problem, it will only work when you have exactly the same number of distinct values in each column.  You can use window functions get the results you want in this case:

```
SELECT distinct on(color, type) color, type, vendor, price
FROM (select f.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by color) as color_rank,
             dense_rank() over (order by type) as type_rank
      from fruits f
     ) f
WHERE color_rank = type_rank
ORDER BY color, type, price;
```

You can easily generalize this by adding more ranks in the subquery and more equality clauses in the `where` clause.

EDIT:

If you have three columns, you would do:

```
SELECT distinct on(color, type, vendor) color, type, vendor, price
FROM (select f.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by color) as color_rank,
             dense_rank() over (order by type) as type_rank,
             dense_rank() over (order by vendor) as vendor_rank
      from fruits f
     ) f
WHERE color_rank = type_rank and color_rank = vendor_rank
ORDER BY color, type, vendor, price;
```

Comment: Thank you. Your result unfortunately contains duplicates: 

`green | apple | cooper |     2`

`green | apple | smith  |     1`

`red   | pear  | cooper |     4`

`red   | pear  | smith  |     3`

The result however should only contain distinct colours and fruits.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM fruits fr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM fruits x1
    WHERE x1.type = fr.type
    AND x1.color < fr.color
    )
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM fruits x2
    WHERE x2.color = fr.color
    AND x2.type < fr.type
    )
    ;
```

Or , if a PK is present for picking the first item of a subset:

```
SELECT *
FROM fruits fr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM fruits x1
    WHERE x1.type = fr.type
    AND x1.pk < fr.pk
    )
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM fruits x2
    WHERE x2.color = fr.color
    AND x2.pk < fr.pk
    )
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you. What is PK? Answer to myself: Primary Key.

Comment: It is not correct, though. PK is Primary Key. (BTW: this problem comes very close to 4NF/5NF/PJNF)